# Есть ли в составе MFC библиотека, реализующая 2-х мерную графику?

Tags: c++, graphics, mfc, winapi

Есть ли в составе Visual C++ библиотека, реализующая 2-х мерную графику? Например, какие-нибудь классы в MFC? Если есть, то дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на её описание в MSDN. Я работаю в MS VS 2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что вы называете 2D-графикой.

Например, класс [`CDC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhhde73.aspx) (device context) имеет методы [`Ellipse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hkxb3kd.aspx), [`ArcTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az78yf4f.aspx), [`PolyLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzaz1k1h.aspx), [`SetPixel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/021s1051.aspx) и т. д. Там же есть и примеры.

Comment: Предположим, мне нужно реализовать две окружности. Первая окружность пустая, а внутри второй вписан отрезок прямой, который имитирует зеркало. Из первой в сторону второй исходит линия, имитирующая луч. Луч отражается от зеркала и от зеркала исходит линия, имитирующая отражённый луч.

Comment: Должна быть возможность перемещения и вращения окружностей.

Comment: Можно ли использовать GDI+ в приложении неуправляемого кода на Visual C++?

Comment: Можно ли использовать Direct2D в приложении MFC для реализации графики?

Comment: Окружность всегда и везде перемещается одним способом: стираем старую и рисуем новую, по новым координатам.  Никакого специального функционала по перемещению геометрических фигур не было  и нет, он просто ни к чему. На  другие 2 вопроса ответ утвердительный.

Comment: Тело функции вращения окружности: `{}` :-)

Comment: Извиняюсь, но хотел бы уточнить: Direct2D и GDI (GDI+) - это две совершенно самостоятельных библиотеки, не зависящих одна от другой? Например, то что можно сделать на GDI (GDI+), то же самое можно сделать на Direct2D? Или же Direct2D это как бы придаток к GDI (GDI+)? Потому что в MSDN написано: Direct2D API is designed to interoperate with existing code that uses GDI, GDI+,